# Misconfigured Properties in XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4

I have a core data model with some entities set up. I have set up some relations without inverse relations. I don't want to have inverse relations, is there a way to surpress those warnings?

I am using iOS 5 and Xcode 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To turn off the warning about this, search for "momc" in Build Settings and you will find `MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS` settings. That should be it.

However, it is better for Core Data integrity to use them. Here's a question that has an answer why: [Does every Core Data Relationship have to have an Inverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764125/does-every-core-data-relationship-have-to-have-an-inverse)