# Modeling a to many relationship in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have two Entities: `Group` and `Member`:

```
Entity name: Group
Relationships:
Member (inverse:Group) (to-many relationship)

Entity name: Member
Relationships:
Group (inverse:Member)
```

So a `Group` can have several members, and the same Member can belong to several Groups, but the `Members` don't know which groups they belong to (there is no inverse)

But something strange is happening. If I add a Member to `GroupA`, he is added successfully. If I add the same member to `GroupB`, he is removed from `GroupA` and added to `GroupB`. Any ideas why this is happening? Have I set up my model correctly?

Edit: Set up inverse relationship, but this didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the cause of what you're seeing, but it's a very, very, very good idea to always have an inverse relationship set up, even if you don't use it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/764572/144755

*Edit: I would suggest adding a* `Groups` *to-many relationship from the* `Member` *entity. It sounds like what is happening is that CoreData is guessing that the relationship from* `Member` `to` `Group` *is to-one*