# Core Data structure between to-many relationship

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does every Core Data Relationship have to have an Inverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764125/does-every-core-data-relationship-have-to-have-an-inverse)

I am following the Core Data [tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started).

In his example he sets up two entities and creates a one-to-one relationship between them. He then states:

> Apple recommends that whenever you create a link from one object to
>   another, you create a link from the other object going back as well.

My question is, if I create EntityA that has a to-many relationship to EntityB, do I need to link back from EntityB to EntityA?

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764125/does-every-core-data-relationship-have-to-have-an-inverse

Comment: @coverback I apologize for the duplicate post. I had been searching and searching and could never find a straight forward answer. (and yes, I did google it and a simple google search didn't bring anything up :P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was having a bit of a brain fart but I found my answer.

The answer is YES! You do have to set a link going back (inverse).

Here is what my model looked like before setting the links back:

[image]

After setting the links back it looks a bit cleaner:

[image]

Here is what the inspector settings look like if anyone else is having the same problem:

[image]

Comment: If you found your answer and are satisfied with it, then you should accept it yourself.

Comment: @coverback Says I have to wait 2 days :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for the sake of data integrity all of your relationships should have an inverse relationship.

Comment: What would be the worst case scenario if a set of entities didn't have an inverse relationship set?

Comment: Data loss would be worst case I believe. For example, when inverse relationships aren't set I have seen data loss when doing an auto migration to a newer version of a core data DB.

Comment: Of course data loss would the worst case! haha The second part of your answer was that I was looking for. Thank you very much +1