# Core Data relationship without inverse when one persistent store is read-only?

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence, data-modeling

I am working on an iOS [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html) model that should use two persistent stores, one of them read-only the other read-write. The read-only store will contain Entities, the read-write store will contain Collections, and there will be a one-to-many relationship between Collections and Entities.

1. I assume this is a (rare) valid scenario for  modeling the one-to-many relationship without an [inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764125/does-every-core-data-relationship-have-to-have-an-inverse) (because the object at one end is read-only, so it can be neither deleted nor updated). Is that so?
2. And if that is indeed so, is there a recommended way for suppressing the corresponding "this is an advanced setting" warning (but not globally suppress all such warnings)?

Answer (score 1):

In Build Settings, you can disable just this one type of warning:

```
MOMC_NO_INVERSE_RELATIONSHIP_WARNINGS == NO;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will globally suppress all such warnings, will it not?

Comment: Understood. But it will globally suppress all warnings for missing reverse relationships, not just the one pertaining to the Collection-to-Entities relationship in particular.

Comment: Right. (To-one and to-many are just properties of a relationship.) It is not a problem I think because a short inspection of the graphical representation of your data model will immediately reveal a link without the reverse. It's really very easy to see and not a "dangerous" removal of a safety feature. --> Don't forget to check the answer!