# Should have an inverse in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does every Core Data Relationship have to have an Inverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764125/does-every-core-data-relationship-have-to-have-an-inverse)

I have the following entities with the relationships:
[image]

A `CombinedSH` must have a `Subject` and a `StudyHour`.
A `Subject` must NOT have a `CombinedSH`.
A `StudyHour` must NOT have a `CombinedSH`.

In my app, it does not make sense that a `Subject` / a `StudyHour` will have a `CombinedSH`.
The problem is that Xcode gives me the following warnings:

> warning: Misconfigured Property: CombinedSH.studyHour should have an inverse.
>
> warning: Misconfigured Property: CombinedSH.subject should have an inverse.

So Xcode says that there should be an inverse - but in my app it doesn't make sense.
What should I do?

Comment: @vikingosegundo: You are right. It is my fault that I did not search for a duplicate before posting an answer, and I did not see your comment before hitting "Post".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can define the inverse relationship from `Subject` to `CombinedSH` and mark it as "optional". Then a "Subject" need not have a "CombinedSH".

Doing so makes Xcode happy, but has also another advantage. Assume you have objects

```
CombinedSH *csh1;
Subject *s1;
```

and

```
csh1.subject = s1;
```

What happens, if `s1` is deleted? Without inverse relationship, `csh1.subject` would point to some deleted object.

But if you define the inverse relationship, and set the "Delete Rule" of that relationship to "Nullify", then deleting `s1` automatically sets

```
csh1.subject = nil
```

and therefore `subject` cannot point to a deleted object anymore.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a "duplicate" (I found it) but I didn't understand why do I have to inverse. Now I got it, your answer is really clear.