# How should this Core Data inverse relationship be modelled

Tags: ios, core-data

This is my first attempt at Core Data and I have the following model:

[image]

In short, my Team model has a relationship of players and also games. My player has a relationship of which team they belong to.

When I get to the Game model I have a relationship called playedList that has all the players who played in that game. As there is a chance that a player although in that team hasn't played in that team's game (injured for instance).

I read this about inverse relationships. [Does every Core Data Relationship have to have an Inverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764125/does-every-core-data-relationship-have-to-have-an-inverse)

but I wasn't sure how I'd model this inverse relationship or how vital it would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should model the inverse, from `Player` to `Game`, as a to-many relationship.  It represents all the games played by a given player, so you might call it `gamesPlayed`.

There are *very* few situations where you are better off not modelling the inverse, and you should assume that all inverses are vital.  In your particular example, I think (going from memory) CoreData will, if you don't specify an inverse, assume that each player can play in only one game.  So, when you add a player to a game, they are mysteriously removed from the game they were previously related to.